# Voting to many wrong answers posted in a short period by a single user

Tags: discussion, serial-voting, wrong-answers

I found a lot of **new wrong answers posted today** by a single new user.

- [Are variable length arrays there in c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22013444/are-variable-length-arrays-there-in-c/49664689#49664689)
- [How to Merge Two vectors in c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49664531/how-to-merge-two-vectors-in-c/49664863#49664863)
- [Undefined reference to defined static private variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23010499/undefined-reference-to-defined-static-private-variable/49663364#49663364)

These answers were posted in a short period today. I found these answers when I was browsing new posts, then I downvoted to prevent others from being misled.

After my third downvote, I realized **all of them are from a single user**.

I know there is a system to detect serial downvotes, thus I'm confused about how to do in this case.

My question is:

- Will my downvotes be considered as *serial downvotes* or *voting fraud* by the detection system?
- How to deal with a lot of new wrong answers posted in a short period by a single user? Because when browsing new posts, the voter even doesn't know they are voting posts from a single user.

Comment: @Turamarth Not quite a duplicate. Since these answers are not "apparently" bad answers, they even look good for non-C++-programmer.  And this user doesn't ask crap questions. The situation here is more subtle, because only those with C++ experience would agree the incorrectness of their answers.

Comment: Oh - is [C++] being hit again?  We only just got rid of the last troll:(

Comment: I haven't touched c++ in years and I can easily see those are crappy answers.